# Subscribing to FirebaseListObservable - property $key does not exist on type any[]

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

My data structure is:

```
users
 KEYnjkhkugl
    uid: JHKJGHKJUYKJAHN
 KEYkjbjhnjs
    uid: UKHUFJGHGBHKTDD
```

Now I need to get a $key, generated by Firebase when I know only the `uid`. So I do this:

```
  getUserKeyFromUid(uid:string) : string {
    let userKey;
    const user$ = this.afDb.list('users', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'uid',
        equalTo: uid
      }  
    })
      .do(console.log);
    user$.subscribe(obj => userKey = obj.$key);
    return userKey;
  }
```

I think it works well, but I cant understand why if I remove `.do(console.log);` I get compilation error under `$key` that

> Property $key does not exist on type any[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use subscribe does not work. But to answer your question, use the firebase sdk like this:

```
getUserKeyFromUid(uid:string) : Observable<string> {
   return this.afDb.object('users/' + uid)
              .do(console.log);
}
```

You can not use subscribe to fill a variable, because the function in subscribe is called async. The way you did it will to the following:
1. let userKey;       // userKey is undefined
2. const user$ = ...  // no effect
3. user$.subscribe(...); // start calling firebase
4. return userKey; // returns undefined
5. obj => userKey = obj.$key // now, userKey will be assigned with the key, but it's to late

So subscribe the observable where you call the function like this:

```
... {
 const userKey$ = getUserKeyFromUid(uid);
 userKey$.subscribe();
}
```

Comment: I believe Firebase has its own implementation of an Observable, called FirebaseObservable. Not sure if it matters here though.

Comment: Subscribe the result of the method where you are calling it. Check my updated answer

Comment: Yeah, u are right. I will move this into Subject under my user authorisation service.